# Dynamic TableLayout Panel

Tags: vb.net, tablelayout, tablelayoutpanel

I want to create tableLayout panel dynamically.

I have achieved this one but my column size is fixed ie 2 but row size dynamically adding - so how to add every row same with height?

Suppose I have

- 2 columns and rows (dynamically)
- 1st column contain radio buttons and second column contain emails

How to add dynamically one by one?

```
radiobutton1      label1
radiobutton1      label1
```

like that?

This is my dynamic table code

```
Dim dynamictablelayout As New TableLayoutPanel
Private Sub dynamictable(ByVal rowcount As Integer)

    Me.dynamictablelayout.ColumnCount = 2
    Me.dynamictablelayout.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 8.333333!))
    Me.dynamictablelayout.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 91.66666!))
    Me.dynamictablelayout.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 3)
    'Me.dynamictablelayout.Name = "TableLayoutPanel1"
    Me.dynamictablelayout.RowCount = rowcount
    For i As Integer = 0 To dynamictablelayout.RowCount - 1 Step 1
        Me.dynamictablelayout.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent))
        Me.dynamictablelayout.Height = 100
    Next
    Me.dynamictablelayout.AutoSize = True
    Me.dynamictablelayout.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(417, 454)
    Me.dynamictablelayout.TabIndex = 0
    Me.dynamictablelayout.AutoScroll = True
    Me.dynamictablelayout.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None
    Me.dynamictablelayout.BackColor = Color.Violet
    Me.dynamictablelayout.RowStyles.Clear()
    Me.dynamictablelayout.ColumnStyles.Clear()
    Me.dynamictablelayout.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.OutsetDouble
    Me.pnlemail.ResumeLayout(False)
    pnlemail.Controls.Add(dynamictablelayout)

End Sub
```

This is my placing control code

```
Dim i as integer=0

Private Sub placedynamiccontrol()

                 For Each email As String In Arremailslist
                   rb.Name = "rb" & email
                   TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(rb, 0, i)

                     lbl.Name = "lbl" & email
                     lbl.Text = email
                     lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(500, 15)
                    dynamictablelayout.Controls.Add(lbl, 1, i)
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

but I am unable to placing controls properly and also I need scrollBar

Please help me

Comment: You can use SetColumn and SetRow to set the location of controls within a WinForms TableLayoutPanel

Comment: Can you tell me how plz ?

Comment: TableLayoutPanel is not an appropriate substitute for DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the column and row of a child control within a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using the [SetColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [SetRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    dynamicTable.ColumnCount = 2
    dynamicTable.RowCount = 5
    For i = 0 To 4
        Dim label = New Label()
        label.Text = i.ToString()
        dynamicTable.SetColumn(label, 0)
        dynamicTable.SetRow(label, i)
        dynamicTable.Controls.Add(label)
    Next
End Sub
```